# Append virtual path to incoming url c#

Tags: c#, .net, url-rewriting, ihttphandler

Is it possible to change the upcoming url so as **localhost/test?t=gowtham** to **localhost/test/t/gowtham** ?

based on my understanding i thought of doing this by extending

```
public class Myhandlers : IHttpHandlerFactory
{ 
  public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
  {
    string s= application.Request.QueryString["t"];
    PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(url,"/t/"+s, context);
  }
}
```

Am I in right path but I could not achieved it? Or else is there any other way?

Comment: What you really trying to do (or to learn)? There probably more standard ways to do that.

Comment: just to rewrite all incoming url.. in the sense if application has url as localhost/test,localhost/test/ss.aspx need to rewrite to  localhost/test/t/gowtham and  localhost/test/t/gowtham/ss.aspx

Comment: Consider using existing tools like [IIS url rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've done stuff like this it's been using `HttpContext.RewritePath()`. The quick 'n dirty method is to put it in globabl.asax, under beging request. 
You can use `Request.Url` to get parts of the requested URL, modify it as you wish, then call RewritePath. Something like this:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Authority = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);   // gets the protocol + domain
    string AbsolutePath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;                     // gets the requested path
    string InsertedPath = string.Empty;                                 // if QS info exists, we'll add this to the URL

    // if 't' exists as a QS key get its value and contruct new path to insert
    if (Request.QueryString["t"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["t"].ToString()))
        InsertedPath = "/t/" + Request.QueryString["t"].ToString();

    string NewUrl = Authority + InsertedPath + AbsolutePath;
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(NewUrl);
}
```

Once you're happy that it's working as expected you can stick it in an HttpModule.

NB: Sorry for incomplete code, not at dev machine and cant' remember all the Request.Url parts. Intellisense should help out though :)

Comment: Ah, I reread your question and think I misunderstood. You said localhost/test?t=gowtham to localhost/test/t/gowtham. Do you want to take the querystring params (t and gowtham) and modify the path to add these as folders in the URL? Or are you saying all incoming requests need to have /t/gowtham/ added to them?

Comment: s at first the value is taken from query params initial and rest all incoming url need to have t/{value form query params}  gowtham in our case

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, it gets the URL for the current request, breaks it up into the left part (protocol/domain) and the right part (the path). Then, it checks for 't' in the query string and, if it exists, creates /t/value (of t) the creates a new URL with the original domain and path with the new path inserted between. This new URL is then executed.

Comment: getting "<path>"is not a valid virtual path. after changing the url

Comment: The code above will take a request of `localhost/test?t=gowtham` and generate a url of `localhost/test/t/gowtham` which we use to rewrite the requested path. Therefore `localhost/test/t/gowtham` must exist (or be handled).